# How do I keep the subdirectories of a directory when I bind mount it to a new docker image?

Tags: docker, mount

## Background

I am running a docker image like the example from facebook's [readme](https://github.com/facebook/infer/tree/main/docker):

```
cd docker/1.1.0/
docker build -t infer .
# mount the local examples directory inside the image
# you can mount your project directory here instead
docker run -it -v $PWD/../../examples:/infer-examples infer /bin/bash
# you should now be inside the docker container with a shell prompt, e.g.
# "root@5c3b9af90d59:/# "
cd /infer-examples/
infer -- clang -c hello.c
```

However, both trying the example verbatim and mounting my own project directory like it mentions leaves me with nothing.  Below is when I ran it mounting my project directory:
[image]

How do I properly bind mount my project directory when creating an infer docker image?

Comment: It says mount your local examples directory. Do you have one on your system where you are running the docker container?

Comment: Your command (the first line in the image you've posted) looks weird, when compared to the line in the commands you've also posted. There's a lot of spaces and 'analyze-this' in it.

Comment: @HansKilian it's a redaction.  It's just another directory where my code is.

Answer (score 0):

Did you extract excluded the root directory (comment line below)? Here's a replay following the instruction with no issue:

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/infer.git
cd infer/docker/1.1.0  # <--- "infer" directory required
docker build -t infer .
docker run -it -v $PWD/../../examples:/infer-examples infer /bin/bash
cd /infer-examples/
ls   
Hello.java  Hello.m  README.md  android_hello  c_hello  demo  hello.c  ios_hello  java_hello
infer -- clang -c hello.c
Capturing in make/cc mode...
Found 1 source file to analyze in /infer-examples/infer-out
1/1 [################################################################################] 100% 46.968ms

hello.c:12: error: Null Dereference
  pointer `s` last assigned on line 11 could be null and is dereferenced at line 12, column 3.
  10. void test() {
  11.   int* s = NULL;
  12.   *s = 42;
        ^
  13. }


Found 1 issue
          Issue Type(ISSUED_TYPE_ID): #
  Null Dereference(NULL_DEREFERENCE): 1
```

[image]

Comment: I still had the same issue.  Following the instructions verbatim resulted in an empty infer-examples directory on the docker image.

Comment: The steps in the answer were tested and copied exactly here. In the directory `infer/docker/1.1.0`, you **must** be able to list files when you do a `ls -l $PWD/../../examples`. Your container should see the same listing when it runs with `-v $PWD/../../examples:/infer-examples`.

Comment: I understand, `ls -l $PWD/../../examples` lists out the directory  perfectly.  But runing that docker run command with the options as you state in your comment resilts in a completely empty directory for me on the container still.

Comment: Updated with a screenshot.